# Join two tables with highest ID in second table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables. First contains products, and second one contains product prices.

```
**Table1** 
productName  |
--------------
     a       | 
     b       |  
     c       |  


**Table2**  
productName  | Price | ID   |
-----------------------------
     a       |   3   |  1   |
     b       |   4   |  2   |
     a       |   1   |  3   |
     b       |   2   |  4   |
     c       |   1   |  5   |    


I need to get products with last price. Product with last price have in second table have the highest ID.

The output should be like:


**Output**    
productName  | Price |
----------------------
     a       |   3   |  
     b       |   2   |
     c       |   1   |
```

So far I can get only for one product but how to get list for all products

```
SELECT table1.productname, table2.price
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.productname = table2.productname
WHERE table1.productname = 'a' AND table1.ID = (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE productname = 'b' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this;)

```
SELECT table1.productname, table2.price
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.productname = table2.productname
WHERE (table2.productname, table2.ID) in (select productName, max(id) from table2 group by productName)
```

Comment: But I don't want to filter by productname 'a'. I need a whole list of products.

Comment: With pleasure, but this will have some performance issue when there are many records in your table. If it does have, please also try the other answer like @Tim Biegeleisen.

Comment: I'm aware of performance issue but for now there will be less than 100 records. Just one more question; how to get all products even they have not defined prices in second table?

Comment: I think you just need to replace `WHERE` to `AND`, then you can get what you want, but if product does not have defined price, its price will be null. And  @Tim Biegeleisen's answer can also do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.productName, COALESCE(t2b.Price, 'NA')
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT productName, MAX(ID) AS maxID
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY productName
) t2a
    ON t1.productName = t2a.productName
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2b
    ON t2a.productName = t2b.productName AND t2a.maxID = t2b.ID
```